# Why is my WCF RIA context throwing FileNotFound exceptions during unit tests?

Tags: wcf-ria-services

I'm trying to write unit tests involving my WCF RIA entity proxies and when I try to access an entity's parent or child properties through an association I get a `FileNotFoundException` when the WebContext class fails to load `System.Xml`.

For example, I have two entities defined in my web project in Entity Framework - `Course` and `CourseUnit`. A `Course` has many `CourseUnit` children. I'm not exposing any RIA contexts or anything to my ViewModels, they are all hidden behind interfaces. I'm using Moq to mock these interfaces and return the standard RIA entity proxies to my unit tests.

This works fine when I'm testing things like

`Assert.AreEqual("title", course.Title)`

where `course` is an instance of the RIA proxy. However, if I do something like

`Assert.AreEqual(0, course.CourseUnits.Count)`

I get the following exception

> FileNotFoundException was unhandled by
>   user code Could not load file or
>   assembly 'System.Xml, Version=2.0.5.0,
>   Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system
>   cannot find the file specified.

And similarly if I execute any code in a unit test that involved one of these relationships then the code throws the same exception. Basically if I ever try to access these properties with association relationships from my tests they break.

The exception actually occurs in generated code. It an be found in the file `[webProjectName].g.cs` in the partial class `Course : Entity` and happens in the CourseUnits getter.

Any ideas?

Edit - I added a reference to the EntityFramework assembly and the exception has changed to the same thing but System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations instead of System.Xml. Needless to say I have tried referencing both assemblies in the unit test project, and it didn't work.

Comment: I suspect this is caused by the fact that I'm referencing a Silverlight project from a Unit Test project, which is infuriating. Microsoft seem to be hell-bent on making sure no one ever write unit tests against RIA services for some reason.

Comment: Instead of using a Unit Test project, take a look at the Silverlight Unit Test framework shipped with the Toolkit (http://silverlight.codeplex.com/). The code model's almost identical, but the testing harness runs in the browser.

Comment: Thanks Kyle, yeah I have used the Silverlight testing framework quite extensively in the past. However I have found that in general it's not conducive to real test-driven development. You really want to be testing with every change you make, at least once a minute but preferably several times for every minute of coding. The Silverlight testing framework, while a nice idea, introduces too much friction to be used as a real unit testing tool, in my opinion. Having said that, it's quickly becoming apparent that RIA itself is not conducive to TDD, so the SLUTF might have to do.